# how to get a complete stack trace in android?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using the following code

```
public static String getCombinedStackTrace(Throwable aThrowable) {

            final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append(aThrowable.toString());
            result.append(',');

            String oneElement;

            for (StackTraceElement element : aThrowable.getStackTrace() ) {
                oneElement = element.toString();
                result.append( oneElement );
                result.append( ",");
            }
return result.toString();
}
```

And it returns the stack trace before "Caused by : " but i want to get after that "Caused by : " also.
Thanks in advance

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(jdbcStatement.java:1102)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(jdbcPreparedStatement.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
```

I can't able to get that "Caused By : " lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

 Writer result = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            //String stacktrace = result.toString();
            //Report += stacktrace;
            printWriter.append( "\n"
                    + "Cause : \n"
                    + "======= \n");

            // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
            // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            while (cause != null) {
                cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                cause = cause.getCause();
            }

            String trace = result.toString(); // here is the result!
            printWriter.close();
```

Comment: Thanks.Again the same issue boss.It displays upto "at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)" but "Caused By " doesn't get

Answer (score 0):

If your Throwable has a cause, it can be retrieved by calling

```
Throwable cause = aThrowable.getCause();
```

Then you can recursivly call

```
getCombinedStackTrace(cause);
```

and concatinate the results to get the complete stack-trace.